# issue with python and whatsapp

Tags: python, file, whatsapp, txt

I extracted the data from whatsapp into a txt file
I need to create 4 columns Date, Time, Name and Message in my output file

```
import pandas as pd

# read file by lines
with open('D:\Analysis\example_chat_whatsapp.txt', encoding="utf-8") as f: 
     data=f.readlines()


# # sanity stats
print('num lines: %s' %(len(data)))

# parse text and create list of lists structure
# remove first whatsapp info message
dataset = data[1:]
cleaned_data = []
for line in dataset:
# grab the info and cut it out
    date = line.split(" ")[0]
    line2 = line[len(date):]
    time = line2.split(" ")[0][:2]
    line3 = line2[len(time):]
    name = line3.split(":")[0][:4]
    line4 = line3[len(name):]
    message = line4[6:-1] # strip newline charactor

    #print(date, time, name, message)
cleaned_data.append([date, time, name, message])

  
#Create the DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(cleaned_data, columns = ['Date', 'Time', 'Name', 'Message']) 
df
```

The issue that I am getting is with variable Time (empty) and Name with a wrong output.
Date and Message are Ok with expected output

Comment: Could you please include all the code and not image links please?

Comment: Give just one line from your file, we are not mediums.

Answer (score 0):

If uncommented `print(date, time, name, message)` prints valid data, then just add 4 spaces before `cleaned_data.append([date, time, name, message])`.

```
for line in dataset:
    # grab the info and cut it out
    date = line.split(" ")[0]
    line2 = line[len(date) + 1:]
    time = line2.split(" ")[0]
    line3 = line2[len(time):]
    name = line3.split(":")[0]
    line4 = line3[len(name):]
    message = line4
    
    row = (date[1:], time[:-1], name[1:], message[2:-1])
    # print("'%s', '%s', '%s', '%s'" % row)
    cleaned_data.append(row)
```

`s[1:]` returns `s` with first character removed, `s[:-1]` returns s with last character removed, and so on.

Comment: I don´t know why I can not include pictures of the output on the post

Comment: No need a picture, just any one line from example_chat_whatsapp.txt.

Comment: ‎[18/12/20 22:20:54] User UV: ‎imagen omitida

Comment: above is an example of one line

Comment: Updated my answer with a solution

Comment: It worked very good only one question ....?? Updated my code